# Jinja2 post-process to append query string to all links?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

What I'm looking to do is this render a jinja2 template but if a particular environment variable is true (edit_mode) I'd like to add ?edit=1 to the href of all "a" tags.

Pseudocode:

```
def render_template(tpl, ctx):
    if ctx['edit_mode']:
        return add_query_string_and_render(tpl, '?edit=1', **ctx)
    else:
        return tpl.render(**ctx)
```

I've considered the following mechanisms:

- Parse the rendered html with beautifulsoup and alter them (ugly, but works)
- Postprocess the source via a jinja2 extension before compilation, but then it'll probably have to have caching disabled

Is there another more elegant solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add it at a routing level? Is "edit" being routed in a different way? Something along the lines of

```
@app.route('page/', defaults={'edit': app.config['edit_mode']})
# if edit do something here
```

(or you could do it very easy using JavaScript if that was acceptable..)

Comment: So that actually doesn't work because edit_mode is being passed in as a query parameter to the current page, and then put into the jinja2 context at render time. It's not in the app config as it's different from user to user.